# Meta data being pulled from wp-login.php

Tags: post-meta, wp-login-form

I'm having some trouble with meta data on my WordPres site.

I have meta tags in the head of my page and they work well, but for some reason when the link is shared on LinkedIn direct chat, it looks like the metadata that is being pulled is from mysite.com/wp-login.php

When I look at the full link it's appears as 
"mysite.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fmysite.com%2F"

How can I either change the metadata on mysite.com/wp-login.php or force the link to grab the metadata from mysite.com

Thanks!

Comment: What link did you share on Linkedin? The second link with the querystring parameters "redirect_to..." usually appears when you're requiring login. The link is appearing that way because it wants the user to login and then they will be directed to mysite.com.

Comment: here is the actual site: https://demoday.coefficientlabs.com/ -- there isnt a login required for the site, so im unsure why this login page is being prompted...

Comment: How can I re-create the issue on Linkedin? Are you copy/pasting the URL from the address bar or using the linkedin icon under a specific post to share in a private chat?

Comment: I am just copy and pasting the link into a direct chat in LinkedIn. I wish I could post an image...but here's a google drive link to view it: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MO4C5XiRAeA1Febh2xEbC2heTXbXEIDQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: So I ended up fixing the issue, but I'm not super sure how haha. I ended up using the Post Inspector tool that LinkedIn provides and it looked totally fine in the tool. This made me think it was a LinkedIn error, but I also simultaneously hid the /wp-login.php page. So I'm not exactly sure which of the two fixed it issue, but it's one of them. Thanks for the help!